# Google consent revocation link

Tags: reactjs, cookies, adsense

Through Google Adsense I activated GDPR confidentiality.

I now have a Google banner on my site that appears by itself on all my pages.

[image]

The problem is that sometimes it appears at the top, sometimes at the bottom and sometimes not at all.

I wish I could always put it in the same place.

After a lot of searching I found NOTHING.

My [website](https://www.waven-build.com/) is in ReactJs / NextJs.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

My "elegant" solution was to hide it completely with this CSS before the `</body>` close tag:

```css
<style>
.google-revocation-link-placeholder{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

**Edit:** After hiding the above, I added a link for same function in my footer:

```
<a href="javascript:googlefc.callbackQueue.push(googlefc.showRevocationMessage)">change ad choices</a>
```

Comment: Might that get you a suspension/ban from Google?

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but I did add a custom one in footer, a href with this link: `javascript:googlefc.callbackQueue.push(googlefc.showRevocationMessage)`

Comment: Yeah, I think that was the “old” way of doing it, I believe that from February onwards it’s got to be more obvious - could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The styling as is on your image that means full width bottom is "broken" you have to put your footer code in the `<footer>` tag then it will appear as the bottom left floating tag which is "correct".

Answer (score -1):

if you use Auto Ads, you may have no such option at all:

> AdSense publishers who create GDPR messages using the Auto Ads functionality do not need to follow this process to implement a consent revocation. **The consent revocation link is shown automatically on their sites.**

src: ["Add a consent revocation link to your app or site"](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10114217?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccode-sample)

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the Google Adsense GDPR banner appears consistently in the same location on your website, you need to have control over its positioning.

1. **Create a Container for the Banner**:
   First, create a container in your React component where you'd like the banner to appear, typically in a layout or page component.

   ```
   <div id="consent-banner-container"></div>
   ```
2. **Override Styles**:
   You might need to override some default styles to ensure consistent positioning. Let's say you want the banner to always appear at the bottom:

   ```css
   .google-adsense-consent-banner {
       position: fixed !important;
       bottom: 0 !important;
       left: 0 !important;
       width: 100% !important;
       z-index: 9999 !important;
   }
   ```

   Note: The class name `.google-adsense-consent-banner` is illustrative. You'll need to inspect the banner and determine the actual class name or ID Google uses.
3. **Move the Banner to Your Container**:
   Once the banner loads, you can move it to the container you've created. This ensures it's always in the position you want.

   ```js
   const banner = document.querySelector('.google-adsense-consent-banner');
   const container = document.getElementById('consent-banner-container');

   if (banner && container) {
       container.appendChild(banner);
   }
   ```

   Since you're using React/Next.js, you might want to use `useEffect` to execute this code once your component mounts.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       const banner = document.querySelector('.google-adsense-consent-banner');
       const container = document.getElementById('consent-banner-container');

       if (banner && container) {
           container.appendChild(banner);
       }
   }, []);
   ```
4. **Test on Different Devices**:
   Ensure you test the placement on various devices and browsers to ensure the banner is always displayed correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The <div> that contains the revocation link contains an inline style like this:
`<div style="width: 100%; height: auto; clear: both;" class="google-revocation-link-placeholder"><div style="border-block: initial !important; border-inline: initial !important; border-start-start-radius: initial !important; ...>`
Pretty much every css property is set to `initial !important`, which makes it impossible to overwrite them through css.